# Redshift COPY import getting aborted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a query:

```
copy quality_temp.temp_qa_leave_list_193de282ea194c169a97bb82a8fcc3b9 (exclusion_value)
from
  's3://quality-staging1/quality-staging1/qa_leave/industry_copy_5eb3f0f88f5fe.csv' iam_role '' IGNOREBLANKLINES delimiter '\^' MAXERROR 1
```

But when I am looking at Redshift console, it shows 'Aborted'.

[image]

I am not able to understand why it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table to see whether any errors have been reported. Otherwise, it might be that the `COPY` process was aborted by your SQL client, perhaps due to a timeout for it taking too long? Where are you running the `COPY` command (console, SQL client)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I used redshift data API and it gets aborted occasionally.
I think default timeout is 0 for data API.